# Pipeline-wide synchronization options

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I am looking for the simple way to execute synchronized blocks inside the pipeline, being sure that no other threads of any workers enter the same section.

Rationale: I have number of external API calls that must be executed sequentially with no concurrent executions from other workers. It's rare condition when such calls have to be executed so it's fine to have blocking section. As solution I could create external service which handles such requests, but I am looking for the simplest possible way to so this.

The basic diagram would look like:

```
if (!checkConditions(...)) {
    withPipelineWiseLock(myHandleId, () -> {
        if (!checkConditions(...)) {
            try {
                call1(...);
                ...
                callN(...);
            } catch (Exception c) {
                ...
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm going to guess that what you want can't be done with just Beam primitives.  The whole remit of Beam is to distribute work far and wide in parallel without synchronization to this granularity.  To achieve, you would have to have a global lock that spans the network.

Comment: That's true that this contradicts Beam paradigm but to be able to create custom Sink and Sources you still need to have such functionality. For example dynamic destination in `BigQueryIO`, it uses `org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.bigquery.CreateTables` to create table with given schema when required. It handles concurrency within worker with simple `synchronized` but as many workers can run the same block it has logic to handle `already exists` and other responses. In my case I have more than 1 external call so logic become too complex to be lock-free.